# Get dynamic value from 'on duplicate key update' in MySQL

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, jdbc

I have a stored procedure that looks something like this:

```sql
DELIMITER ;;
  CREATE PROCEDURE test_proc(IN _key INT, IN _value VARCHAR(45), OUT _counter INT)

  BEGIN
    INSERT INTO test_table(key, value, counter)
    VALUES (_key, _value, 1)
    ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
      value = _value,
      counter = counter + 1;

    SELECT counter FROM test_table WHERE key = _key INTO _counter;

  END ;;
DELIMTER ;
```

Is it possible to get the counter out of the insert statement without having to query the database for it? My schema is actually quite a bit more complicated than this with millions of records and a large numbers of operations so I would like to be as efficient as possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, no. You will have to perform a `SELECT` query.

Comment: I need to get the dynamic counter out of the insert, not the ID. The counter is just a column in the database to keep track of how many times the record has been updated.

Comment: And this is why we read more carefully, ladies and gentlemen. The first part still stands; You'll have to use a `SELECT`.

Comment: Thank you much! That is what I thought but wanted to ask anyway. If you fix your answer I will up-vote etc it.